# saving multiple results in a array in java

Tags: java, arrays

how can I populate an array with results from multiple operations like a harmonic sum: Harmonic= 1+1/2+1/3+1/4.......+1/n
My incomplete version looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=1, harmonic=0, y=2;
        int[] n;
        n = new int[];

       // for populating the array ?!?!?!
       do {n = {x/y}} 
       y++;
       while (y<=500);

       //for the sum for loop will do...
        for (int z=0; z<=n.length; z++){
             harmonic += n[z];
            }
        System.out.println("Harmonic sum is: " + harmonic);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things... you should use a double data type since you dont wan t/need truncated values, and you should use for that collections instead of arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x = 1, harmonic = 0, y = 2;
    List<Double> arc = new ArrayList<>();

    do {
        arc.add(x / y);
        y++;
    } while (y <= 500);

    for (Double double1 : arc) {
        harmonic += double1;
    }
    System.out.println("Harmonic sum is: " + harmonic);
}
```

the output will look like:

> Harmonic sum is: 5.792823429990519

## edit:

using streams:

```
double streamedHarmonic = arc.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
```

Comment: I am at the begining and still learning the basics, that's why I was trying to do it with arrays. I will study your solution. Thx a lot !